# Is there a fast way to verify y is actually the output of a model on an input?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a deep learning model M with set random seed. For a pair (x,y) I want to verify M(x) == y without actually doing the inference process itself because it takes too long. Is there a way to do this?

The situation is that I give a client the model M. He will run M(x) with arbitrary x and send (x, M(x)) back. I want to check that he actually ran the model and not just sent some made up value. I also don't want to hire another client to cross-check.

The client could include some extra information to the result and not just x and M(x).

This seems to be somewhat related to proof as in blockchain's proof-of-work.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. In general no, there's no way to do that: you want to check the result of a function without actually calculating the result of the function. Also usually the inference process (i.e. apply the model, as opposed to training the model) is not very costly, but if it's still too costly to do it every time you could perform random checks on X % of the pairs.

Comment: Hi Erwan, I edited the question. It may be impossible to check the result without calculating the result of the function, but in this case we actually calculate it once in the client side. Is there some extra information to include in the sent back result to prove he actually ran it?